# convert a list of lists to an array of list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am trying to convert a list into an array.
The list is:

`list = [[59.99,
  58.648,
  58.608,
  62.944,
  51.648,
  49.397,
  44.766,
  40.066,
  35.641,
  33.825,
  31.112,
  28.644,
  26.441,
  24.592,
  26.767],
... ,
 [253.99,
  7.8,
  58.28,
  744.4,
  59.08,
  10.37,
  2.9,
  33.356,
  64.2,
  4.5,
  3.18,
  24,77,
  7.18,
  92,5,
  95.87]]`

I have tried this :

`A = numpy.array(list)`

but when I type `A`, I get the following array:

`array([list([59.99, 58.648, 58.608, 62.944, 51.648, 49.397, 44.766, 40.066, 35.641, 33.825, 31.112, 28.644, 26.441, 24.592, 26.767]),
       ...,
       list([253.99, 7.8, 58.28, 744.4, 59.08, 10.37, 2.9, 33.356, 64.2, 4.5, 3.18, 24,77, 7.18, 92,5, 95.87])],
      dtype=object)`

How can I get ride of `list()` in the array ?

Comment: What do you see for `set(map(len, L))` where `L` is your input list (don't shadow built-ins, i.e. call your input `L` not `list`)? If your sublists are not the same length, what you see is inevitable.

Comment: That is a 1d array containing lists. Given the mix of list sizes it can't create a 2d array.

Comment: yes my sublists are not the same length. Maybe I have to extract each list and zero-pad it so that I can convert the whole list to an array

Comment: It's just that I want to feed the whole thing to a neural net and I doesn't make any sense to say that a sample " s " has a feature " f " when it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sublists with mismatched lengths. As such, an array of lists is inevitable. As you suggested, you can zero-pad your sublists.

Here's one solution via a list comprehension:

```
L = [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]

n = max(map(len, L))

res = np.array([i + [0]*(n-len(i)) for i in L])

print(res)

array([[0, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 0],
       [7, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: well it's working. I am afraid I connot escape the zero padding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your list does not contain lists of equal length, and that is the reason why numpy is unable to convert directly.
For instance, if you try :

```
mylist = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
l = np.asarray(mylist)
```

This will work as expencted, since lists contained in mylist are of the same length.
Still, you can try doing it in two steps:

```
mylist = [[59.99, 58.648, 58.608, 62.944, 51.648, 49.397, 44.766, 40.066, 35.641, 33.825, 31.112, 28.644, 26.441, 24.592, 26.767],[253.99, 7.8, 58.28, 744.4, 59.08, 10.37, 2.9, 33.356, 64.2, 4.5, 3.18, 24,77, 7.18, 92,5, 95.87]]
list_of_arr = [np.array(x) for x in mylist]
arr = np.array(arr)
```

so as to have arrays instead of lists to deal with

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
from itertools import chain

A = numpy.array(list(chain(*your_list)))
```

and don't name your variable `list` it is a reserved keyword

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use list as your variable name.
list is a python reserved keyword.
Use mylist or something else.

One thing you can do is create an empty list: compiledlist.

Then loop over the different arrays in mylist and extend them to compiledlist.

```
compiledlist = []
for sublist in mylist:
    compiledlist.extend(sublist)

A = np.array(compiledlist)
```